# Is it possible to have an OUT parameter to a function?

Tags: php

There is a function :

```
function keyAndNatExistsForTheExercice($nat, $exercice, $hint, $pk) {
    $critere = array();
    $critere['nat_impot_code'] = ($nat == "" ? "IS NULL" : $nat);
    $critere['exer_annee'] = $exercice;
    $critere['param_exer_hint'] = $hint;
    $enreg = $this->val_param_exercice->lireParCritere($critere);
    if ($enreg['cnt'] > 0)
        // I want to set value to the $pk param here
    return ($enreg['cnt'] == 0 ? false : true);
}
```

As you can see I want to set a value to the `parameter` inside the `function` , and I want to use that value elsewhere. Is that possible ?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: so the param must be initialised before calling the function ?

Comment: You would never want to do that, it would break the single responsibility principle - just do it outside the function, wherever you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the variable by reference, something like:

```
<?php
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a=5;
foo($a);
// $a is 6 here
?>
```

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Answer (score 1):

You could return an array with the true or false value for 'cnt' and the value you want to give $pk.

```
$array['returnValue'] = ($enreg['cnt'] == 0 ? false : true);
$array['pk'] = //whatever you want to give it here.

return $array;
```

Then you only need to change the value of the parameter.

Else you give the $pk parameter by reference so that it'll give out the change of the value.

```
function keyAndNatExistsForTheExercice($nat, $exercice, $hint, &$pk) {
    $pk = //some Value
}
```

Or you save the value into the session and work with that value that's saved there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reference to that variable. E.g.:

```
$nat = 5;
$exercice = true; // Typo?
$hint = 'Hint';
$pk = 1;

keyAndNatExistsForTheExercice($nat, $exercice, $hint, $pk);
```

**NOTE**

You can't pass reference value directly to function:

```
keyAndNatExistsForTheExercice($nat, true, $hint, $pk); // Will throw an error as &$exercice must be variable.
```

---

```
function keyAndNatExistsForTheExercice($nat, &$exercice, $hint, $pk) {
    /* ... */
}
```

---

Also keep in mind that you can also return multiple values from function too:

```
list[$a, $b] = myFunction();

function myFunction() {
    return array('value Of A', 'value Of B');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it into $_SESSION[] variable, so as long as the user is in, this value is stored (server-side).
However you need to have the session already running.

Comment: I do not suggest using this method, because there is much simpler ways.